# code who will take values from <span> element and sort unique values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to write code who will take values from  element and sort unique values and after all display in screen. My problem is that I can not sort unique values. it seems to me that problem is in array. Thank you for help and sorry for grammatical mistakes.

```
<pre id="a">
<span>D</span>   <span>C</span> <span>E</span> <span>E</span> <span>D</span> </pre>
<form method="POST" id="form">
<input type="hidden" id="lan" value="" name="number">
<input type="submit" value="patvirtint">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> var M=document.getElementById('a');
//   counts <span> elements
var N=M.getElementsByTagName('Span');

var largo = N.length;

document.getElementById("form").getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute("value", largo);
</script>

<?php

 // Taking values from form to php code

 if (!empty($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['number'])) {
 $counter = 0;
 $band = $_POST['number'];


 while ($counter<=$band-1) {
 // looping values with javascript help  

 $labas1[]='"'.'<script type="text/javascript"> var M'.$counter.'=document.getElementById(\'a\');
  var N'.$counter.'=M'.$counter.'.getElementsByTagName(\'Span\')['.$counter.'].innerHTML; document.write(N'.$counter.');</script>'.'",';
 $counter++;
 $result = array_unique($labas1);
}
print_r($result);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array `$labas1` don't have what you think, try this:

```
<pre id="a">
    <span>D</span>   <span>C</span> <span>E</span> <span>E</span> <span>D</span> 
</pre>
<form method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="hidden" id="lan" value="" name="number">
    <input type="submit" value="patvirtint">
    <input type="hidden" id="myDATA" value="" name="myDATA"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript"> var M=document.getElementById('a');
    //   counts <span> elements
    var N=M.getElementsByTagName('Span');

    var largo = N.length;


    var myData = Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < N.length; i++) {
        myData[i]=N[i].innerHTML;
    }
    document.getElementById("myDATA").value=myData;
    document.getElementById("form").getElementsByTagName('input')[0].setAttribute("value", largo);
</script>

<?php

// Taking values from form to php code

if (!empty($_POST['number']) && isset($_POST['number'])) {    
    $counter = 0;
    $band = $_POST['number'];
    $my_labas1=$_POST['myDATA'];
    echo $my_labas1;
    $result=explode(",", $my_labas1);
    $result = array_unique($result);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($result);
    echo "</pre>";
    asort($result);
    print_r($result);
}
?>
```

Comment: doesn't give any result in screen. error mesage : Cannot set property 'value' of null of myDATA.

Comment: Excuse me for lost time, I glad to help you